# Why won't this session variable work...?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a game for class and when the user completes a level they proceed to the next. But as they can't be allowed to access the URL directly I have tried to create a PHP session variable in the JavaScript `If` statement for winning the game, like this:

```
if (passOnLevel == 0 && passengerCarrying == 0) {
    alert("You Win!");
<?php $_SESSION['levelCompleteC'] = 'levelOneComplete'; ?>
    window.location.href='gameL2.php';
}
```

In the `gameL2.php` file (level 2) I have this `If` statement at the top of my page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['RobotName'], $_SESSION['traction'], $_SESSION['passenger'], $_SESSION['levelCompleteC'])) {
....
....
........
```

However the `$_SESSION` variable for `levelOneC` to check whether the successfully completed the level seems to automatically set itself when level one loads so it doesn't actually check to see if they won the level.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: PHP runs on the server when the page is being created, not on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is rendered BEFORE the page loads, which means that you can't come along and insert PHP code to be executed after the page loaded. Use AJAX to do your desired operation.

For easy refrence, Google "XMLHttpRequest" or see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).